# My styling is ignoring my CSS and instead using the 'element style'

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a tooltip for my site's contact form (can be seen [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/) in the contact section.)

I'm having some problems in positioning the tool-tip correctly. As I'm sure you can see, the tooltip is not near the field it relates to. I have put in a left value of 200px within my css (which you can see in the .formerror class [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/css/validationEngine.jquery.css))

However the element is still pulling through a left value of 279. Developer tools tell me this is from 'element style'. I'm confused as to where this value is coming from, can anyone help?

Comment: The library you're using is setting the style values inline, which will always override whatever is in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the demo here...

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoPositioning.html

...the code is working exactly as it should but the arrow on your graphic is centered instead of being aligned to the left so it looks a bit weird.

There is a section on the following page which tells you how to position your tooltip:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Look for 'promptPosition'.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I understand the problem now. I attempted to fix it using !important but then I realised this value is created depending on where you click, otherwise it'll always be fixed! Thanks for the link, I didn't think to look there 'doh!

Answer (score 2):

The `left` position you set in your CSS is being overridden in the element's `style` attribute by some JavaScript. You can add `!important` to the end of your `left` value to prevent the `style` attribute (or anything else) from overriding it, but it may not be the best solution (please see http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).